# How to display two questions categories in menu from the same database Quiz Android

Tags: java, android

I added a second category of questions, but I do not know how to use the code so that was visible this category on the list..
Please help to me
what to do to the other category was also visible?
my category in database:
[image: 1]

```js
private void addQuestion3() {

        QuestionHist q0 = new QuestionHist ("1.Historia Polski - Quiz z wiedzy ogólnej ","1", "0","0", "0", "0", "0", "0","none");
        this.addQuestion3(q0);
        QuestionHist q1 = new QuestionHist ("2.Historia Świata - Wiedza Ogólna ","1", "0","0", "0", "0", "0", "0","none");
        this.addQuestion3(q1);
}


 public void addQuestion3(QuestionHist his) {
// SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_SUBJECT, his.getSUBJECT());
        values.put(KEY_LEVEL, his.getLEVEL());
        values.put(KEY_QUES, his.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, his.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, his.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, his.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, his.getOPTC());
        values.put(KEY_OPTD, his.getOPTD());
        values.put(KEY_TRIAL1, "0");
        values.put(KEY_TRIAL2, "0");
        values.put(KEY_TRIAL3, "0");
        values.put(KEY_TRIAL4, "0");
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, his.getIMAGE());
// Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_HIS, null, values);
}


// looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                QuestionHist his = new QuestionHist();
                his.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                his.setSUBJECT(cursor.getString(1));
                his.setLEVEL(cursor.getString(2));
                his.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(3));
                his.setANSWER(cursor.getString(4));
                his.setOPTA(cursor.getString(5));
                his.setOPTB(cursor.getString(6));
                his.setOPTC(cursor.getString(7));
                his.setOPTD(cursor.getString(8));
                his.setTRIAL1(cursor.getString(9));
                his.setTRIAL2(cursor.getString(10));
                his.setTRIAL3(cursor.getString(11));
                his.setTRIAL4(cursor.getString(12));
                his.setIMAGE(cursor.getString(13));  //13, because the trials are between OPTD and IMAGE
                quesList.add(his);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
  return quesList;
    }


public List<QuestionHist> getQuestionsFromSubject(String subjectArg) {
        List<QuestionHist> quesList = new ArrayList<QuestionHist>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_HIS;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToPosition(1)) {
            do {
                if (subjectArg.equals(cursor.getString(1))) {
                    QuestionHist hist = new QuestionHist();
                    hist.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                    hist.setSUBJECT(cursor.getString(1));
                    hist.setLEVEL(cursor.getString(2));
                    hist.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(3));
                    hist.setANSWER(cursor.getString(4));
                    hist.setOPTA(cursor.getString(5));
                    hist.setOPTB(cursor.getString(6));
                    hist.setOPTC(cursor.getString(7));
                    hist.setOPTD(cursor.getString(8));
                    hist.setTRIAL1(cursor.getString(9));
                    hist.setTRIAL2(cursor.getString(10));
                    hist.setTRIAL3(cursor.getString(11));
                    hist.setTRIAL4(cursor.getString(12));
                    hist.setIMAGE(cursor.getString(13)); //13, because the trials are between OPTD and IMAGE
                    quesList.add(hist);
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }

public List<QuestionHist> getQuestionsFromSubjectAndLevel(String subjectArg, int levelArg) {
        List<QuestionHist> quesList = new ArrayList<QuestionHist>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_HIS;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToPosition(1)) {
            do {
                if (subjectArg.equals(cursor.getString(1)) && levelArg == Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2))) {
                    QuestionHist hist = new QuestionHist();
                    hist.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                    hist.setSUBJECT(cursor.getString(1));
                    hist.setLEVEL(cursor.getString(2));
                    hist.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(3));
                    hist.setANSWER(cursor.getString(4));
                    hist.setOPTA(cursor.getString(5));
                    hist.setOPTB(cursor.getString(6));
                    hist.setOPTC(cursor.getString(7));
                    hist.setOPTD(cursor.getString(8));
                    hist.setTRIAL1(cursor.getString(9));
                    hist.setTRIAL2(cursor.getString(10));
                    hist.setTRIAL3(cursor.getString(11));
                    hist.setTRIAL4(cursor.getString(12));
                    hist.setIMAGE(cursor.getString(13)); //13, because the trials are between OPTD and IMAGE
                  quesList.add(hist);
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }

public String getSubjects() {
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_HIS;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        String dbSubjects = "";
        if (cursor.moveToPosition(0)) {
            dbSubjects = cursor.getString(1);
        }

        return dbSubjects;
```

and my code in activity:

```
 btngra = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btngra);
    btnscores = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnscores);
    btnsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
    btnchangesettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnchangesettings);
    listSubjects = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);

    String subjectsRaw = db.getSubjects();
    final String[] subjects = subjectsRaw.split("/");

    // Definiowanie  adaptera
    // Pierwszy parametr - Kontekst
    // Drugi parametr - Układ rzędzie
    // Trzeci parametr - identyfikator TextView z którym są zapisywane dane
    // czwarty - tablica danych

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, subjects) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);


                    /*YOUR CHOICE OF COLOR*/
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            ;

            return view;
        }
    };


    // Przypisywanie adapterow do listy
    listSubjects.setAdapter(adapter);
    listSubjects.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);



    // ListView Item Click Listener
    listSubjects.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long qid) {
            final String subject = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            // Set the item as checked to be highlighted
            for (int i = 0; i < listSubjects.getCount(); i++) {
                listSubjects.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            //listSubjects.setItemChecked(0, true);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);


            //przejscie do kategorii
            btngra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Options.this,
                            HistQuestionActivityCategory.class);
                    Bundle bun = new Bundle();
                    bun.putString("subject", subject);
                    intent.putExtras(bun);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    resultsSent = false;
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

and my screen:
[image: 2]

How can I add a second category? Please help to me

My Activity aftery modify:

```
 btngra = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btngra);
    btnscores = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnscores);
    btnsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
    btnchangesettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnchangesettings);
    listSubjects = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);

    List<String> subjects = db.getSubjects();
    //final String[] subjects = subjectsRaw.split("/");


    // Definiowanie  adaptera
    // Pierwszy parametr - Kontekst
    // Drugi parametr - Układ rzędzie
    // Trzeci parametr - identyfikator TextView z którym są zapisywane dane
    // czwarty - tablica danych

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,subjects) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);


                    /*YOUR CHOICE OF COLOR*/
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            ;

            return view;
        }
    };


    // Przypisywanie adapterow do listy
    listSubjects.setAdapter(adapter);
    listSubjects.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);



    // ListView Item Click Listener
    listSubjects.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long qid) {
            final String subject = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            // Set the item as checked to be highlighted
            for (int i = 0; i < listSubjects.getCount(); i++) {
                listSubjects.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            //listSubjects.setItemChecked(0, true);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);


            //przejscie do kategorii
            btngra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Options.this,
                            HistQuestionActivityCategory.class);
                    Bundle bun = new Bundle();
                    bun.putString("subject", subject);
                    intent.putExtras(bun);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    resultsSent = false;
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

And QuizHelper:

```
    private void addQuestion3() {

        QuestionHist q0 = new QuestionHist ("1.Historia Polski - Quiz z wiedzy ogólnej ","1", "0","0", "0", "0", "0", "0","none");
        this.addQuestion3(q0);
        QuestionHist q1 = new QuestionHist ("2.Historia Świata - Wiedza Ogólna ","1", "0","0", "0", "0", "0", "0","none");
        this.addQuestion3(q1);
        QuestionHist q2 = new QuestionHist("1.Historia Polski - Quiz z wiedzy ogólnej ","1","Chrzest Polski miał miejsce w roku", "956", "966", "965", "978", "966","drawable/chrzestpolski");
        this.addQuestion3(q2);
        QuestionHist q3 = new QuestionHist("1.Historia Polski - Quiz z wiedzy ogólnej ","1","Którą bitwą zakończyło się tzw. 100 dni Napoleona?", "Bitwą Narodów ", "Bitwa pod Borodino", "Bitwą pod Waterloo", "Bitwa nad Berezyną", "Bitwą pod Waterloo","drawable/napoleonbonaparte");
        this.addQuestion3(q3);
        QuestionHist q4 = new QuestionHist("1.Historia Polski - Quiz z wiedzy ogólnej ","1","W którym roku powstało Księstwo Warszawskie?", "W 1807", "W 1896", "W 1900", "W 1859", "W 1807","drawable/ksiestwowarszawskie");
        this.addQuestion3(q4);
        QuestionHist q5 = new QuestionHist("1.Historia Polski - Quiz z wiedzy ogólnej ","1","Król Polski Władysław III Warneńczyk zginął w 1444 roku w bitwie pod Warną. Ile miał wówczas lat?", "20 lat ", "44 lata ", "56 lat ", "30 lat ", "20 lat ","drawable/warna");
        this.addQuestion3(q5);
        QuestionHist q6 = new QuestionHist("1.Historia Polski - Quiz z wiedzy ogólnej ","1","W którym państwie władzę sprawował Francisco Franco?", "W Hiszpanii", "W Portugalii", "We Francji", "We Włoszech", "W Hiszpanii","drawable/franco");
        this.addQuestion3(q6);


public List<String> getSubjects(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        // Equivalent to the following SQLite query:
        // SELECT DISTINCT col_subject FROM table_his ORDER BY col_subject
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                true,
                new String[]{KEY_SUBJECT},
                TABLE_HIS,
                null,null,null,
                KEY_SUBJECT + "ASC",
                null
     );
        List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            // iterate over the cursor
            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
                subjects.add(cursor.getString(0));
            }
        }finally {
            cursor.close();// release resources
        }
        return subjects;
        }



    /*public String getSubjects() {
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_HIS;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        String dbSubjects = "";
        if (cursor.moveToPosition(0)) {
            dbSubjects = cursor.getString(1);
        }

        return dbSubjects;

    }

*/
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrTR5.jpg)

after modification there is a problem for argument: true what did I do wrong?

Comment: What exactly is giving you problems? Are you just asking how to insert data into a database on Android?

Comment: I added a second category, but I do not know how to show it

Comment: This my second category: 2.Historia Swiata - Wiedza Ogolna ","1", "0","0", "0", "0", "0", "0","none");

Answer (score 0):

Your `getSubjects()` method doesn't do what you intend it to do. Currently it selects everything from the table (which is unnecessary, you only need the subject column), moves to the first row, and returns the subject. In other words, it will only ever return one value. It also doesn't close the `Cursor` when it's done. In your `Activity`, the line `final String[] subjects = subjectsRaw.split("/");` probably doesn't do anything since only one subject was returned.

Here's an implementation that should work much better:

```
public List<String> getSubjects() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    // Equivalent to the following SQLite query:
    // SELECT DISTINCT col_subject FROM table_his ORDER BY col_subject
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            true,                      /* distinct */
            TABLE_HIS,                 /* table */
            new String[]{KEY_SUBJECT}, /* columns */
            null, null, null, null     /* where, where args, group by, having */
            KEY_SUBJECT + " ASC",      /* order by */
            null                       /* limit */
    );

    List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        // iterate over the cursor
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            subjects.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close(); // release resources
    }
    return subjects;
}
```

You won't need the `String.split()` call with this approach, you can use the `List` right away.

Comment: Thank you for replay, after add your implementation  I have a problem for argumet: true, what did I do wrong? ;(

Comment: @Robert There was a mistake in my code, I have updated it. There should be an extra `null` argument before the order by clause.

Comment: Very, very thank you very much !! Everything works!!
You are great!!